# Error while deploying on sepolia network

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, sepolia

hardhat.config.js ->

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers");
require("dotenv").config();
console.log("1");
const SEPOLIA_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: SEPOLIA_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  }
};
console.log("2");
```

package.json ->

```
{
  "name": "rpsls-contracts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.0",
    "ethers": "^6.8.1",
    "hardhat": "^2.19.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1"
  }
}
```

I am trying to deploy using the command npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia
but nothing is showing on my terminal. I did console.log so it is just showing 1212
deploy.js ->

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

 async function main(){
  const RPSLSF = await hre.ethers.deployContract("RPSLSFactory");
  // Deploy the contract.
  await RPSLSF.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("Contract deployed to:", RPSLSF.target);
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Solidity code ->

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed

pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

contract RPSLSFactory {
    RPSLS[] private gameSessions;
    mapping (address => RPSLS[]) private userGameSessions;

    event NewGameSession(address indexed gameSession);
    function createGameSession(
        bytes32 _move1Hash,
        address _player2
    ) external payable {
        RPSLS gameSession = (new RPSLS){value: msg.value}(
            _move1Hash,
            msg.sender,
            _player2
        );
        gameSessions.push(gameSession);
        userGameSessions[msg.sender].push(gameSession);
        userGameSessions[_player2].push(gameSession);

        emit NewGameSession(address(gameSession));
    }
    function getGameSessions()
        external
        view
        returns (RPSLS[] memory _gameSessions)
    {
        return userGameSessions[msg.sender];
    }
}

contract RPSLS {
    enum Move {
        Null, Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock
    }
    address public player1;
    address public player2;

    bytes32 move1Hash;

    Move public move1;
    Move public move2;

    uint256 public stake;

    uint256 public TIMEOUT_IN_MS = 5 minutes;
    uint256 public lastTimePlayed;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == player1);
        _;
    }

    event Player2Played(address indexed _player2, Move indexed _move2);
    event GameSolved(address indexed winner);
    event GameTied();
    event GameTimedOut(address indexed fallbackWinner);

    constructor(bytes32 _move1Hash, address _player1, address _player2) payable {
        stake = msg.value;
        move1Hash = _move1Hash;
        player1 = _player1;
        player2 = _player2;
        lastTimePlayed = block.timestamp;
        // const contract = await ContractFactory.deploy('uintValue')
    }

    function play (Move _move2) external payable {
        require(msg.value == stake, "Insufficient funds for move. Make sure you stake the required amount of ETH for the transaction to succeed.");
        require(msg.sender == player2);
        require(move2 == Move.Null, "Move already played");

        move2 = _move2;
        lastTimePlayed = block.timestamp;

        emit Player2Played(player2, _move2);
    }

    function solve(Move _move1, string calldata _salt) onlyOwner external {
        require(player2 != address(0), "Player 2 should make his move in order to solve the round.");
        require(move2 != Move.Null, "Player 2 should move first.");
        require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_move1, _salt)) == move1Hash, "The exposed value is not the hashed one!");
        require(stake > 0, "Winner is already determined.");

        move1 = _move1;

        uint256 _stake = stake;

        if (win(move1, move2)) {
            stake = 0;
            (bool _success) = payable(player1).send(2 * _stake);
            if (!_success) {
                stake = _stake;
            }
            else {
                emit GameSolved(player1);
            }
        }
        else if (win(move1, move2)) {
            stake = 0;
            (bool _success) = payable(player2).send(2 * _stake);
            if (!_success) {
                stake = _stake;
            }
            else {
                emit GameSolved(player2);
            }
        }
        else {
            stake = 0;
            (bool _success1) = payable(player2).send(_stake);
            (bool _success2) = payable(player1).send(_stake);
            if (!(_success1 || _success2)) {
                stake = _stake;
            }
            else {
                emit GameTied();
            }
        }
    }

    function win(Move _move1, Move _move2) public pure returns (bool) {
        if (_move1 == _move2)
            return false; // They played the same so no winner.
        else if (_move1 == Move.Null)
            return false; // They did not play.
        else if (uint(_move1) % 2 == uint(_move2) % 2) 
            return (_move1 < _move2);
        else
            return (_move1 > _move2);
    }

    function claimTimeout() external {
        require(msg.sender == player1 || msg.sender == player2, "You're not a player of this game.");

        require(block.timestamp > lastTimePlayed + TIMEOUT_IN_MS, "Time has not run out yet.");

        uint256 _stake = stake;
        stake = 0;

        if (player2 == address(0)) {
            (bool _success) = payable(player1).send(_stake);
            if (!_success) {
                stake = _stake;
            }
            else {
                emit GameTimedOut(player1);
            }
        }
        else if (move2 != Move.Null) {
         (bool _success) = payable(player2).send(_stake * 2);
            if (!_success) {
                stake = _stake;
            }
            else {
                emit GameTimedOut(player2);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your deploy.js script?

Comment: Is there any error shown?

Comment: No error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Developer Advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here.

You can follow this guide, which will explain to you how to deploy with Hardhat.

#### Initialize a New Project

Create a [new Hardhat project](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started#quick-start). During initialization, opt to install `hardhat-toolbox`.

#### Install Dependencies

Ensure you've installed OpenZeppelin contracts:

```sh
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
```

#### Smart contract

In the contracts directory, create a file named `Token.sol` and paste the following:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("Token", "TKN") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}
```

#### Configure Hardhat

Add your private keys and RPC to the following.

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

const SEPOLIA_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: SEPOLIA_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.20",
};
```

#### Deploy Script

Here's a sample `deploy.js`:

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  console.log("Deploying contract...");

  // Deploy the contract
  const FICEToken = await hre.ethers.deployContract("Token");

  // Wait for the transaction to be mined
  await FICEToken.waitForDeployment();

  // Log the address of the deployed contract
  console.log("Contract deployed to:", FICEToken.target);
}

// Execute the script and handle errors
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Remember that this will only work with the same smart contract I posted.

If you change the name of the contract, edit it in this line:

```js
hre.ethers.deployContract("Token");
```

#### Compilation and Deployment

Compile your smart contract:

```sh
npx hardhat compile
```

Deploy it:

```sh
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia
```

It will return a result like this:

```sh
Deploying contract...
Contract deployed to: 0xa804D8845263719e2E9bff14930cE738950FB623
```

Feel free to reach out if you need more help!

Comment: I have attached deploy.js and solidity file also. I did what you said but it didn't work for this project. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was able to deploy your contract on Sepolia using your contract and your deploy script. https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xa725f0a5015c16bd4f8e31462099df39c4c99889

Maybe it's an issue with the RPC? Do you get any error?

Comment: It's an error due to rpc i think. I deployed the same contract on some other pc using the same code and it was deployed.